# Angular - How can I access Template variable/reference from typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

In my Angular project I am trying to access the value present in `<td [innerHTML]='rupee.replaceHTML' #term></td>` and assign it to vaiable `newdata.`

More on the functionality here, I have 2 buttons `change` and `concourse`. The value present in below HTML will change when I press `concourse` button. I was to save that changed value in variable  `newdata` using `localStorage` so that I can access it later.

How can I  `access that html value and store it in new_data`?

.html file

```
<mat-list-item>New Life</mat-list-item>
 <mat-list class="textFields">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td [innerHTML]='rupee.replaceHTML' #term></td> ---> Access whatever value is here
      </tr>
     </table>                
 </mat-list>

//button
<button mat-raised-button type='button' (click)='concourse(kada, term)'>Confirm
```

component.ts

```
export class Pinky { 
  @ViewChild('term') editElem!: ElementRef<HTMLTableDataCellElement>;
    

//button function       
concourse(rec: FillData, nada: HTMLTableDataCellElement) {
  const { a,b,c,d } = rec;
  let maan= nada.innerText;
  localStorage.setItem('FillData', JSON.stringify(rec));

   var new_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FillData') || '{}') as FillData

-------------------//Can I access #term value here?-------------------------

    new_data.{{?}}= maan;                 ----------> Assign the  value here ?
    localStorage.setItem('FillData', JSON.stringify(new_data));
}
```

Interface

```
export interface DraneMan {
  maan:string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a `@ViewChild('term')`
so you can just get it from `this.editElem.innerHTML`.

What's more, you have a binding `[innerHTML]='rupee.replaceHTML'`, so, reading from the DOM something that is bound seems like the wrong data flow.
I would just use `ruppee.replaceHTML` as source of truth.

Comment: You mean to use `newData.maan.editElem.innerHTML` ? I have add interface. If I use this it says `Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'string'.ts`